# How to override language files in Typo3 version 7.6?

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I really need to know how to override languagefiles from extensions. For example, I have powermail installed and I have one language file from that extension that I need to override.

So I've got an extension called website_head and in that I created the file:

```
typo3conf\ext\website_head\Resources\Private\Language\Overrides\powermail\Resources\Private\Language\locallang.xlf
```

And the file I want to override is:

```
typo3conf\ext\powermail\Resources\Private\Language\locallang.xlf
```

When I clear the caches it does not change (but when I change the original it does change the text, it's just not overriding)

Also this is what's inside the override locallang.xlf file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<xliff version="1.0">
    <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="messages" date="2014-05-02T12:00:00Z" product-name="powermail">
        <header/>
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="validationerror_mandatory">
                <source>Custom text</source>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/7.6/Internationalization/Translation/Index.html:

You probably need to:

1) declare your XLF:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['locallangXMLOverride']['EXT:powermail/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf'][] = 'EXT:website_head/Resources/Private/Language/Overrides/powermail/Resources/Private/Language/custom.xlf';
```

2) override a label:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<xliff version="1.0">
     <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="messages" date="2013-03-09T18:44:59Z" product-name="website_head">
             <header/>
             <body>
                     <trans-unit id="validationerror_mandatory" xml:space="preserve">
                             <source>Custom text</source>
                     </trans-unit>
             </body>
     </file>
</xliff>
```

Comment: Step 2 is just adding that code in my "custom.xlf" file in your example right? Anyways, I've got it working. The first line of code you showed fixed the problem! Thank you very much, learned something today.